# Subdivision modifier turns mesh into one dimension object

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I get this strange error every time I apply the subdivision modifier.
Could you please say what can cause this? Thank you!
[image]
[image]

Comment: does this happen if you do the same thing in a new .blend file?

Comment: How do you apply it? It is disabled.

Comment: Yes! In every file and in every mesh! It only worked properly when I applied a mirror modifier under the subdivision one in one project.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: It is applied in the second sceenshot @Crantisz No? Excuse me I'm super new in Blender...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be this [bug with AMD graphics cards](https://developer.blender.org/T94936).

Go to Edit → Preferences →  Viewport → Subdivision and **disable GPU subdivision**.

[image]