# rain rig not rendering eyebrows

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh, rigging

I'm currently trying to render scenes with animations I made on Blender's rain rig. I stumbled across the problem where the eyebrows are not making it into the final render (Ctrl + F12). I have checked my restriction toggles and the "Disable in Renders" is not turned on. Any idea what happened here?

---

[image]

**What is seen in the viewport before the render**

---

[image]

**Blender Render view**

---

[image]

**Eyebrows are not disabled**

Comment: Pls provide blend file - you could delete anything except the eyesbrows if the error still persists - upload. Thanks

Comment: @Chris
I experimented with the eyebrows in a separate scene. I deleted everything except it. Sadly, it also does the same thing. Here's the .blend file:

https://we.tl/t-Ynsqmk3oMr

Comment: i rendered your blend file: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5mVq.jpg ...so i can "see" your eyebrows...

Comment: @Chris Any idea what went wrong on my end? Do you think it's a render settings problem? This is the result of my blender render:

https://imgur.com/a/lsQTHM8

Comment: No, if it would be your render settings, I would have the same problem. I just can assume a graphic‘s card problem. But that’s just a vague guess.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for the help! I'll still try to pinpoint the problem. I can try reinstalling Blender and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @Chris btw what Blender version are you using?

Comment: Blender 3.2 alpha

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who encounters this, I figured out why it does that after tinkering with it for so long. It has a **Subdivision** modifier and it previews it in real-time. Basically, if the mesh still has that modifier, the mesh disappears. IDK the specifics of it but that is what I have observed. The fix for this is to delete that modifier. I hope this helps in the future.

---

[image]

**Before**

---

[image]

**After**

Comment: Looks like this problem: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263422/subdivision-modifier-turns-mesh-into-one-dimension-object/263426#263426

Comment: @Crantisz Thank you so much! This was a cleaner way of fixing the problem!